# How to fix "not a procedure" error

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define (comp f g)
  (lambda (x)(f (g x))))

(define (complement f) (cond ((equal? (comp f (lambda (g) g)) #t) #f)
                            (else #t)))

((complement odd?)2)
```

It keeps saying that `((complement odd?)2)` is not a procedure. I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @AlexisKing It's the same OP lol.

Comment: You should edit your existing question, not post a new one

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try doing just

```
(define (comp f g) (f g))

(define (complement f) (lambda (g) (cond ((comp f g) #t) (else #f))))

((complement odd?) 2)
```

Comment: You should say what you changed any why it makes a difference.

Comment: It's always evaluated to #t even when it should be to #f.

Comment: That's because your logic is off. I've updated my answer to fix that too. Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Doesn't seem like `compose` looks ok anymore. `complement` should only have `(comp not f)` as its body.